# How to test react-jsonschema-form components with @testing-library/user-event

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, react-jsonschema-forms, user-event

I faile to write even the most simple tests for [react jsonschema form](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form). Because changes to input elements seem not to be reflected in the dom.

Given a minimal form like this:

```
const schema = {
  title: "Todo", type: "object",
  properties: {
    title: { type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task" }
  }
};

const formData = { title: "First task aaa" };

export class MyForm extends React.Component {
  render() { return <Form schema={schema} formData={formData} />; }
}
```

a minimal test would look like

```
test("changes input", async () => {
  render(<MyForm />);
  const input = screen.getByRole("textbox");
  expect(input.value).toBe("First task aaa");
  await userEvent.type(input, "567890", { delay: 10 });
  expect(input.value).toBe("567890");
});
```

(Complete sample over at [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-react-jsonschema-form-forked-8fgvo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fform.test.js&theme=dark).)

After typing in the Form field the text `First task aaa` should be replaced by `567890`. Unfortunately it is not.`input.value` keeps the value `First task aaa`.

I thied many variants of firing events and waiting for results but always the value of the input element stays unchanged.

What am I missing to test the `<MyForm />` component? Seems pretty standard to me.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem as well and it looks like react-jsonschema-form is not playing well with `fireEvent` or `userEvent`.

However, using the react-doms [Simulate](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#simulate) function, it does work:

```
import React from "react";
import { Simulate } from 'react-dom/test-utils'
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MyForm } from "./form.js";

// Tests in codesandbox fail in Safari - use Firefox or Chrome
// click on the "Tests" tab in the upper right.

test("changes input", async () => {
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<MyForm />);
  const input = getByLabelText("Title");
  expect(input.value).toBe("First task aaa");

  Simulate.change(input, { target: { value: '567890' }})

  expect(input.value).toBe("567890");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of you are using `fluent-ui` Form library for your UI, and this will bind the input value with your `formData.title` field. This may interrupt `userEvent.type` action. To simply test `userEvent.type` functionality, you can make your form component with pure input element, and bind your default value as defaultValue of the input element.

For example:

```
export class MyForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <input type="text" defaultValue="First task aaa" />;
  }
}
```

Incase you will see below error on your test output:

```
expect(element).toHaveValue(567890)

    Expected the element to have value:
      567890
    Received:
      First task aaa567890

      13 |   expect(input).toHaveValue("First task aaa");
      14 |   userEvent.type(input, '567890');
    > 15 |   expect(input).toHaveValue('567890');
         |                 ^
      16 | });
```

As you can see, `userEvent.type` will append additional input to the current value. So, you can just use `Simulate.change` functionality or use `userEvent.clear` function before your `userEvent.type` line like below.

```
test("changes input", async () => {
  render(<MyForm />);
  const input = screen.getByRole("textbox");

  expect(input).toHaveValue("First task aaa");
  userEvent.clear(input);
  userEvent.type(input, "567890");
  expect(input).toHaveValue("567890");
});
```

This answer could helpful for your question. 
Cheers!